# adding artefacts in Archiva not through its interface

Tags: maven, archiva

How can I insert artefact in [archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) not through its web interface.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to upload artifacts using maven.

Please refer to the Archiva Users Guide, Section `Deploying to Repository` for the details.

Answer (score 1):

The following methods are available:

- upload via the user interface (I presume this is the one you refer to as the web interface)
- connect via any WebDAV client at `http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/repo-name` (adjust according to your configuration)
- use HTTP PUT with basic authentication to the same location as the WebDAV URL (this is the method that other tools like Maven, Ivy, etc. would use)
- drop the file into the correct place in the file system and wait for Archiva's scanner to pick up the changed artefact

As Torsten's answer indicates, uploading using Maven's deploy phase or `deploy:deploy-file` goals (or equivalent from another build tool) is likely what you want since it will take care of constructing the correct path for the artefact and pushing any associated metadata, assuming you are using Archiva as a Maven artefact repository.

Comment: Yes, I'm using archiva.That helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have an upload screen tru the web ui.
See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSXe26inf0Y